# How to print function in haskell

Tags: haskell

Im trying to print the value of a factorial function however it does not work.

```
fac n = if n < 2 then 1 else n * fac (n-1)

main = do

    putStrLn "Enter a number: "  
    number <- getLine 
    print $ number >>= fac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the (>>=) there. Just

```
print $ fac number
```

should be enough. However, `number` needs to be an `Int` or `Integer`. So you either need to use `read`, or, much simpler, instead of using `getLine`, use `readLn`, which will do `getLine` and automatically convert it to an Integral type.

Comment: `readLn` throws an `IO` exception if it fails. You can catch it manually, or use the `Alternative IO` instance: `fix $ \try_again -> readLn <|> (putStrLn "Please try again." *> try_again)`. Alternatively, you can use `readMaybe` from `Text.Read`: `numberMaybe <- readMaybe; case numberMaybe of {Nothing -> handle the error; Just n -> ....}`. To try till you succeed, `fix $ \try_again -> maybe (putStrLn "Please try again." *> try_again) pure . readMaybe =<< getLine`.